# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: : org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets.<init>(DDDD)V

Tags: java

While creating a **jfreechart** im getting following error and I am not sure whats the reason for it..any help??

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.ui.RectangleInsets.<init>(DDDD)V
    at org.jfree.chart.axis.Axis.<clinit>(Axis.java:146)
    at org.jfree.chart.StandardChartTheme.<init>(StandardChartTheme.java:227)
    at org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory.<clinit>(ChartFactory.java:229)
    at modules.images.Chart.createChart(Chart.java:67)
    at modules.images.Chart.<init>(Chart.java:59)
    at modules.images.Chart.main(Chart.java:506)
```

Comment: Looks like a version mismatch between the packages that provide `org.jfree.chart` (JFreeChart) and `org.jfree.ui` (JCommon). Which versions do you have of both packages? Have you tried downloading the newest versions of both?

Comment: i have jcommon-1.0.16 and jfreechart-1.0.14 and it worked in my other same type of project earlier..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have jcommon-1.0.0.jar (or a later version) on your classpath.

Comment: I have  jcommon-1.0.16.jar version

Comment: Then make sure you don't have any OTHER versions of JCommon on your classpath.

Comment: dude it worked..thanks alot, i had conflicting jar problem :) i had diff versions of jcommom removed all an kept only jcommon-1.0.20 finally the chart is up :)